# VSCode GitLens extension: remove "ago" from dates

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

Using VSCode's GitLens extension, is it possible to show the relative time since a change without writing "ago"? Currently if a line in a file was changed 4 years ago, GitLens will write out "4 years ago" in the git blame in the left gutter, but I would prefer it just to say "4 years" or maybe even "4 y". Is this possible? My current date format setting is empty:

```
"gitlens.blame.dateFormat": ""
```

Comment: If the provided answer worked for you, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${agoOrDateShort}`.
I found it in the GitLens Settings / File Blame menu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).